# Background image crashes android

Tags: android, android-layout, background, background-image

My application crashes when i put background line like in this code. When i delete this line my application works fine and also when i use another photo it also works. What's the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/table2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The background for the main screen works fine also. But in the second page, it is problamatic.

Comment: In your drawable folder is there a file table2 ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'crashes' , show log cat please

Comment: The dimesions 2500x1900 , is it about that?

Comment: It could be about the size. That size image will eat up ~19MB of your (probably 48MB) heap on its own, and specifying it in xml will cause two allocations of that size as the system scales it down for you. Look in your LOGCAT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to you all. I changed the dimensions from 2500x1900 to 1280x920, now it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using only drawable folder to store all images.then change storage folder for high resolution images in **drawable-xhdpi** folder or higher.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure about the image path if it is in drawable folder..put it inside Mipmap folder in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the size of your image anything above 300kb may tend to constantly crash your app. You can always use image compression Softwares to reduce the size of your image.