# What is the full screen image sizes for an Android app? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, background-image

I have a background image in an activity, its size was set to 1280x920, as adviced in [Background image crashes android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242303/background-image-crashes-android). This works perfectly.

I also have a full screen activity (sticky immersive), with the same configuration, the image is "stretched" out vertically. What should be the size of the image so that there is no scaling or stretching at all? (While the image occupies the full screen, off course)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on screen. Android supports multiple screens. That's way in project we have x-hdpi, hdpi, xx-hdpi folder. As source:

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no one size.  Every Android device has different screen sizes.  What you need to do instead is provide multiple sizes and accept some stretching or shrinking on odd sized devices.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html for more advice.